# Given the hints solve the puzzle

Tags: riddle, word

> I sometimes float, at times I don't,
>
> Some people like me, some don't.
>
> Millions see me, millions don't,
>
> Let me be upfront, I'm not any kind of boat.
>
> Almost everyone has seen me at least once in their lifetime,
>
> Mind you, I only arrive if I'm given some time.
>
> Don't give me too much time else my host will evolve,
>
> If you want my host you definitely should resolve.
>
> If you don't like me, throw me out,
>
> if you don't I'll spread out.

**What am I?**

Comment: +1 just to ruin your 666 reputation. *joke* - now seriously, maybe is too broad. at least for the first 5  sentences

Comment: @lois6b I'll send you a message when it's 777. I'll add a few more hints ASAP. I need a few mins to think :)

Comment: -1 for trying to rhyme "don't" with "boat".  (not really)

Comment: @TrevorPowell I was trying to reduce the scope of the answer by that line.   A lot of people would answer boat, ships, cruise etc seeing float on the first line.

Comment: I was going to guess "dynamic IP address," but it doesn't quite work.

Comment: @pnschofield Programming and Computer Science infiltrates our brains. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it -

> Milk Cream

I sometimes float, at times I don't,

> Cream floats over normal milk but not over skimmed milk

Some people like me, some don't.

> Very true

Millions see me, millions don't,

> People who drink skimmed milk don't see me.

Let me be upfront, I'm not any kind of boat.

> Cream isn't a boat, cruise or any such vehicle and doesn't float on water.

Almost everyone has seen me at least once in their lifetime,

> Ofcourse.

Mind you, I only arrive if I'm given some time.

> It appears after the boiled milk is kept away for some time.

If you don't like me, throw me out,

if you don't I'll spread out.

> If you don't like it you just remove it and throw it out. Else it will spread into entire milk.

Don't give me too much time else my host will evolve,

> It can be used to make several other dairy products.

If you want my host you definitely should resolve.

> If you want milk (i.e I float on it, therefore host) you should resolve to drink it before it turns into curd.

Comment: I'm going to edit it to clarify some clues :)

Comment: Sure. Go ahead.

Comment: up for a chat? I want some feedback to make better puzzles. You haven't given a link to any social media.

Comment: Techidiot Please join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48419/room-for-abhirath-mahipal-and-techidiot whenever you get the time :)

Answer (score 5):

It might generate multiple answers. Here is one -

Is it -

> Trash

I sometimes float, at times I don't,

> Float on water. Sometimes not.

Some people like me, some don't.

> Normal people don't like it while trash retailers do

Millions see me, millions don't,

> A clean country with millions dont see it around. Rest see it.

Let me be upfront, I'm not any kind of boat.

> Not sure if there is anything to prove here.

Almost everyone has seen me at least once in their lifetime,

> Offcourse.

Mind you, I only arrive if I'm given some time.

> Given some amount of time it gathers.

If you don't like me, throw me out,

if you don't I'll spread out.

> Self Explanatory.

Update

Don't give me too much time else my host will evolve,

> If you don't clean it up for a long time, it will spread the diseases.

If you want my host you definitely should resolve.

> If you want to identify the disease, you need to resolve and find out the trash which might have caused it.

Another answer might be

> A thought

Comment: Nice answer +1. I edited the question 5 mins before you posted an answer. You were probably writing this answer when I edited the question. If possible try fitting the two new hints as well :)

Comment: @Abhirath Done. :)

Comment: @Abhirath Mahipal- Added another one here.

Comment: You could have posted another answer....

Comment: I thought I might catch downvoters if I did that. You never know :) Anyway, both are mine so no problems.

Comment: @Techidiot Make it a separate answer so that I can accept it. You'll be getting 25 more points :D

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

> MOULD? (My original thought was a VIRUS, but mould seems to fit at least the second line better.)

*I sometimes float, at times I don't,*

> Probably? Different kinds of mould etc.

*Some people like me, some don't.*

> Mould on blue cheese can be delicious, but most mould is unwanted and disliked.

*Millions see me, millions don't,*

> Mould is often seen, but sometimes it's *not* seen - it might be inside your walls.

*Let me be upfront, I'm not any kind of boat.*

> Indeed.

*Almost everyone has seen me at least once in their lifetime,*

> Yes, probably.

*Mind you, I only arrive if I'm given some time.*

> Mould needs time to grow.

*Don't give me too much time else my host will evolve,*

*If you want my host you definitely should resolve.*

> Not *entirely* sure about these lines, but mould definitely had a 'host'.

*If you don't like me, throw me out,*

*if you don't I'll spread out.*

> Pretty self-explanatory, I think.

Comment: I figured Mushrooms for the same reasons as this

Comment: Nice try but not the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think

> Viral Diseases

I sometimes float, at times I don't,

> water-borne diseases

Some people like me, some don't.

> People like to see other people get ill. (Bad guys!)

Millions see me, millions don't

> Millions of people are sick due to virus every year.

Let me be upfront, I'm not any kind of boat.

> Probably just for rhyme

Almost everyone has seen me at least once in their lifetime,

> People get sick at least once in their lifetime,mainly due to viral diseases

Mind you, I only arrive if I'm given some time.

> Yes, You experience the first symptoms only after the virus enters your body and starts to replicate

Don't give me too much time else my host will evolve,

> Viruses have RNA as their genome. They evolve at a faster rate. Host means humans who start developing resistance to such diseases.

If you want my host you definitely should resolve.

> Not sure,probably means it takes effort to save a person from a deadly viral disease

If you don't like me, throw me out,

if you don't I'll spread out.

> Probably means, prevent the disease or it will spread at a very fast rate through your family...

Comment: Nice attempt +1. I expected this answer. So I clearly mentioned almost everyone has **seen** me in their life :)

Answer (score 0):

It is

> Bacteria?

I sometimes float, at times I don't,

> They do both

Some people like me, some don't.

> When they give disease we hate them, when given in vaccines we like them (some hate that too :D)

Millions see me, millions don't,

> They are visible to many organisms, and invisible to many

Let me be upfront, I'm not any kind of boat.

> :)

Almost everyone has seen me at least once in their lifetime,

> Everyone gets vaccine has seen them.Then there are many examples like rotten food, feces etc

Mind you, I only arrive if I'm given some time.

> They take time to gestate and in proper conditions

Don't give me too much time else my host will evolve,

> They affect their host: in humans positive and negative effects are there , they rot food etc

If you want my host you definitely should resolve.

> I didn't understand this sentence much, one explanation is to save the host (food/animal/human) one needs a solution (resolve)

If you don't like me, throw me out,

> Anything which has bacteria growth and is not liked is thrown out.

if you don't I'll spread out.

> We all know this and have experienced this :D

Comment: Heh, we both posted pretty similar answers at the same time :-)

Comment: Um, wat - you shadow-edited your answer to nothing just seconds before I edited it to fix the spoilertags, so now [it looks like](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/45531/revisions) I wrote your answer for you!

Comment: Haha @randal'thor, my text was not getting hidden. Isn't ">!" the right syntax?

Comment: Yes, but you put "!>" at first, which doesn't work.